# Omnet++ sumo and veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

I'am a beginner in **omnetpp** .
i have to create a vehicle in **omnet** using **inet** then to connect it via **veins** to **sumo** how could i start my project.

Answer (score 2):

Veins 4.7.1 comes with a subproject called `veins_inet`, which you can use to create an INET simulation that uses Veins for node mobility (which, in turn, uses SUMO to simulate vehicle movement). Simply import the `subprojects/veins_inet` directory as a project into the OMNeT++ IDE, then create an INET simulation that configures both `veins_inet` and `veins` as project references.

You can also download [Instant Veins 4.7.1](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/), a virtual machine image that has all of this set up already. This should give you a running simulation in two minutes.

Comment: Okay thanks so when i install veins_inet it can create nodes to communicate because my project is about iov i have to create multiple cars and object to communicate each other then present them on sumo